# JQuery call popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am an Apprentice and never worked with Javascript.
My Javascript function calls a popup. This works on the first button but doesn't work on all the following and since the application is constantly adding buttons(same class) I cannot hardcode. I guess ther will be a solution with JQuery...
**("open")** and **("openPopupUseExisting")** are the two buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('blackout').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('popup').className = "";
            document.getElementById('blackout').className = "";
            document.getElementById('popupUseExisting').className = "";
        }, false);
        document.getElementsByClassName("open")[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('popup').className = 'visable';
            document.getElementById('blackout').className = 'visable';
        }, false);
        document.getElementsByClassName("openPopupUseExisting")[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('popupUseExisting').className = 'visable';
            document.getElementById('blackout').className = 'visable';
        }, false);
        document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('popup').className = "";
            document.getElementById('blackout').className = "";
            document.getElementById('popupUseExisting').className = "";
        }, false);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Set click event on some parent element, for example: `$('body').on('click', '.open', function(e) { .... });` and it will work every time. Do **not** use same ID on multiple elements on page, it has to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]
> ```

See that `0`?

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object. You are getting the first item off it.

Loop over it with a `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry mate, this will not work. The OP says "the application is constantly adding buttons(same class)". His problem is with dynamically added elements being unbound, not just with the node list that already **exists** on the `window.onload`. Check out my answer to see if you agree.

Comment: @FilipeMerker — I was interpreting that as "The application is under development and new sections are being added" rather than "New sections are being added dynamically while the application is running."

Answer (score 0):

Friend, you don't need to add an entire library just in order to bind dynamically added elements.

You can bind the `document` for click event, and then check if the clicked element is the one you want. It prevent dynamically added elements to be unbound, since it aims for the entire document.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('blackout')) {
        // your fancy magic with .blackout
    } else if (e.target.classList.contains('open')) {
        // your fancy magic with .open
    }
}, false);
```

If you really want to use jQuery, as you ordered, it's quite simple, use the `on` method

```
$('.open').on('click', function(){
  // your fancy magic with .open
});
```